# How do I view the SwaggerUi when using Azure API Management

Tags: swagger, azure-api-management

I have an API in Azure with address;

http://webapiapplicationXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net

and the Swagger UI at

http://webapiapplicationXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

Putting this into the Azure API Management gives me an address of:

http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-api.net/Time/api/TimeZoneInfo

I want to see the SwaggerUI.  I've tried the obvious URLs but got:

> { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

What is the URL to see the SwaggerUI when the API is hosted in Azure API Management?

Answer (score 6):

Usually people don't use the Swagger UI anymore once an API is behind API Management.  The reason being that the developer portal provides the equivalent and better functionality.

If you really do want to expose the underlying SwaggerUI then you can create an additional operation in API Management that points to the SwaggerUI.  The reason you are getting 404 is because API Management is saying that you are trying to access a resource that is not defined as an API Management operation.

You should be able to create the API operation like this
[image]

Comment: I want it because I took so long to make it look nice :-)

I don't see how I can add SwaggerUI as a New Operation. Do you have any suggestions as to what parameters I should use?

Comment: That worked.  I didn't understand what a "Template" was

Comment: Actually I was wrong.  This didn't work.  I was still looking at the API Swagger and no tthe one exposed through API Management.  If I do what you suggest above I get this in the browser;

swagger

http://example.com/api

api_key

Explore

Comment: @Richard210363 It could be that more paths are needed to allow the pass through.  Let me investigate.