# Get/generate swagger url of Azure APIm API

Tags: azure, url, swagger, azure-api-management

I have setup apis in Azure APIm and individual actions are working by their respective url.
I want a Swagger uri of this API which is having azure domain and lists all the actions in it.

For example, by default APIm provides a sample api named "Echo API" whose url becomes: https://testresource.azure-api.net/echo

Now, I understand that there is an option on the API context menu to export it in Swagger format.
But what I am looking for is such a url that render this specifications online:
https://testresource.azure-api.net/echo/swagger

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931872/how-do-i-view-the-swaggerui-when-using-azure-api-management?rq=1) have an answer to add an endpoint for swagger/ui/index. Which I believe is having an endpoint in native api and configure as an action. Is there any way APIm generate/provide such a url for already setup APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [MayankBargali-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/mayankbargali-msft/)  and [Sam Cogan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/sam-cogan/) Posting your suggestion as answer to help other community members.

> 1. You need to use the Create/Update API to pass in the URL of your swagger file. You can find an example
>    [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/apis/create-or-update#apimanagementcreateapiusingswaggerimport?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404).
> 2. Unfortunately, API only accepts it as the swagger file while importing the swagger file as documented in the [request
>    body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/apis/create-or-update#request-body).
>    You can try uploading your swagger file to your storage account or any
>    path which is publicly accessible.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/687043/import-swagger-file-programatically-to-azure-apim.html.